# Deploying Laravel without regenerating key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

We're deploying our Laravel app with Capistrano, which runs these commands after the deployment

`cd /var/www/html/site/current
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:clear
php artisan migrate`

It deploys nicely, but running the "key:generate" command also logs out every active user.

In some cases, we would only need to update the files. Is it enough to leave out just the key:generate? Simply updating the files doesn't always seem to be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run this command only once during installation and then use the same key to avoid this kind of problems. So, just remove this line from the script:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation

Comment: Even if we make changes to the Auth side of the app?

Comment: @Apeli well, it depends. But generally yes, you shouldn't change it because it's used by [encrypter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/encryption) and if you save encrypted data to DB or use it for sending emails (password reset etc), you'll have trouble with these too.